# Getting value from a different table

Tags: visual-studio

```
sql = "UPDATE tblpayment SET ADDONS=SPRICE-(SELECT RPRICE FROM `tblreservation` r WHERE TRANSNUM= & dtgList.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)" WHERE TRANSNUM= & dtgList.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
```

tblpayment:

```
SPRICE | ADDONS
----------
4800   |    0
```

tblreservation:

```
RPRICE|
----------
3600
```

I want to get the difference of SPRICE and RPRICE and put it in ADDONS column. Kinda new here. Sorry.